# Drawing a line with user input

Tags: c#

Sample picture to understand the concept

[image]

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to enter the values for the start and end of the line, then display it onto the picturebox.

I am stuck on the logic. 
Currently I am trying to pass two values from the textboxes into two seperate functions then to a button which will display the line output onto the picturebox but have hit a plateau

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Content item for the combo box
   class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Value;
        public Item(string name, int value)
        {
            Name = name; Value = value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            // Generates the text shown in the combo box
            return Name;
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Put some stuff in the combo box
        shapelist.Items.Add(new Item("Line", 1));
        shapelist.Items.Add(new Item("Rectangle", 2));

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Display the Value property
        Item itm = (Item)shapelist.SelectedItem;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", itm.Name, itm.Value);
    }
    public void readend()
    {
        int val = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(txtEnd.Text, out val))
        {
            //parse was successful
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input string cannot be parsed to an integer");
        }
    }

    public void readstart()
    {
        int val = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(txtstart.Text, out val))
        {
            //parse was successful
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input string cannot be parsed to an integer");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're getting there but work to do. Some points; in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you're getting the `Item` but not doing anything with it. You're also calling `Console.WriteLine` in a WinForms application, not a console application (calling it won't do anything). You'd have to draw the live in a `PictureBox` (which I don't see anywhere in the code). I'm not seeing where `readstart()` and `readend()` are called at all so are unnecessary purely in terms of drawing a line (though needed for validation).

Comment: why would you have 2 separate functions for readstart+readend, you mention passing 2 variables but it just seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you out here.

Few things:
1. You don't need these functions to achieve your end goal: `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`, `readstart` and `readend`; Perhaps for your  your understanding and debugging.
1. I will add one more button to your setup and call it "Clear", to clear the drawing, just for demonstration.
1. You don't need a full blown class for `Item`. Just use an `enum`

With these things out of the way, the below code should help you out

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    bool setToPaint = false;
    int startVal, endVal;
    ArtifactType selectedArtifact;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
```

shapelist.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ArtifactType)).OfType().ToArray());
            shapelist.SelectedIndex = 0;

```
        pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (setToPaint) {
            if (selectedArtifact == ArtifactType.Line)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, startVal, 100, endVal, 100);
            else if (selectedArtifact == ArtifactType.Rectangle)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, startVal, startVal, endVal - startVal, 100);
        }
    }

    private void Draw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int.TryParse(txtStart.Text, out startVal);
        int.TryParse(txtEnd.Text, out endVal);
        selectedArtifact = (ArtifactType)shapelist.SelectedItem;

        setToPaint = true;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        setToPaint = false;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}


enum ArtifactType { None, Line, Rectangle }
```

**Explanation**:

1. First, when you click `Draw`, you want to capture the inputs from the control and do some validation, etc. These captured inputs need to be stored into some member variables.
2. In the constructor, you can see how to extract all the values in the enum and put it in the dropdown. You can add only the ones you want or add all of them, like I have done. Next in the constructor, you want to hook-up to the `Paint` event of the `PictureBox`. This is where you would really draw your shapes.
3. Let's skip over the `Paint` for now, and go to the Draw button click handler. The first 3 lines capture the input into private variables. This is where you might want validate and bail out on failure. Once everything is valid, we `setToPaint = true`. This is the flag we use to make sure we paint the shapes only on request.  And once we click Clear, the flag will be reverted. After enabling the flag,  we have to force the control to repaint its surface, so the painting logic will be rendered. That is achieved by the `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` call
4. In the Clear button Click handler, we simply revert the `setToPaint` flag and `Invalidate` the picturebox so the system renders it again, and this time it will skip drawing our shapes.
5. Now in the `PictureBox.Paint` handler, all our code is inside the flag. This is how we associate the rendering with the flag. Inside that `if`, we simply draw the shapes that we want based on our captured private variables. You should make sure you create the requested `Pen` (width and color both) for this drawing and appropriately link the `start` and `end` values to the shape

Hope this helps you understand how this is done